# ASP.NET MVC language change link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that it's in two languages using Resources. To allow the server to present the site in the apropiate language (depending on the one that's configured in the user's browser) I put the following in my web.config:

```
<globalization culture="es-es" uiCulture="auto" />
```

How can I add a link to change the uiCulture? I want to store the selection in a cookie and if it's not present, then fall back to the browser configuration... Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html). It uses Session to store the current user language preference but the code could be very easily tweaked in order to use a cookie. The idea is that you will have a controller action:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
{
    var langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", lang)
    {
        HttpOnly = true
    };
    Response.AppendCookie(langCookie);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

and then in `Global.asax` you could subscribe for the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event in order to set the current thread culture based on the value of the cookie:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var langCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"];
    if (langCookie != null)
    {
        var ci = new CultureInfo(langCookie.Value);
        //Checking first if there is no value in session 
        //and set default language 
        //this can happen for first user's request
        if (ci == null)
        {
            //Sets default culture to english invariant
            string langName = "en";

            //Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
            {
                //Gets accepted list 
                langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);
            }

            langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", langName)
            {
                HttpOnly = true
            };


            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(langCookie);
        }

        //Finally setting culture for each request
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

        //The line below creates issue when using default culture values for other
        //cultures for ex: NumericSepratore.
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
    }
}
```

Now this being said using cookies and session to store current language is not SEO friendly. What I prefer doing when I need a localized application is to use a special route which will contain the language:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new 
    { 
        lang = "en-US",   
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

and then prefix all my urls with the language. This provides unique urls for different languages so that robots can properly index all content. Now all that's left is to modify the `Application_AcquireRequestState` method so that it uses the `lang` token of the url and based on its value set the proper `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

And now when you wanted to change the language you would simply generate the proper link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Page index en français", "index", new { lang = "fr-FR" })
```

Comment: Great! I have now a working version using the cookie. I'll try the other way later when I have time. SEO is not really important for my site, but I also think it's a clearer way to do it...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Do you think that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is safe in every deployment scenario, i.e. is it guaranteed that every Request is processed in a separate Thread?

Comment: Can `ci` actually be `null` in the code above?
Was your `if (ci == null)` section meant to be the `else` part of the `if (langCookie != null)`?

Comment: You can add expire date for not expiring after browser session end

`var langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", lang)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Expires=DateTime.Now.AddYears(10)
                };`

Answer (score 5):

An alternative and I feel it is more flexible

```
 protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        if (RouteData.Values["lang"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString()))
        {
            SetCulture(RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myappculture"];
            if (cookie != null)
            { SetCulture(cookie.Value); }
            else
            { SetCulture(HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]);}
        }
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }

public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
    {

        SetCulture(lang);
        // Little house keeping
        Regex re = new Regex("^/\\w{2,3}(-\\w{2})?");
        returnUrl = re.Replace(returnUrl,"/" + lang.ToLower());
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

private void SetCulture(string lang)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);

        // Force a valid culture in the URL
        RouteData.Values["lang"] = lang;

        // save the location into cookie
        HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie("myappculture", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
        _cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(_cookie);
    }
```

In the view

[image: Multilingual setup in view]

I kept the resource in a different project as follows

[image: Resources in a different project and Its usage]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `App_GloabalResources` to store your resx language files, all you have to do is add a drop down which changes the current thread's UI Culture and this will automatically select the right resx language file to display.

Comment: Are you sure this actually works?  I suspect that the `UICulture` will be forgotten between page reloads, since the thread will get recycled by another request.

Comment: I'll be doing this in a new MVC 5 website over the next few weeks so will retry it. Darin Dimitrov's response looks like a good solution for MVC though.

Answer (score 1):

App_GloabalResources is not the right place the resources when it comes to MVC programmering. See http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.no/2012/05/right-way-to-use-resource-files-for.html

Comment: Please do not post answers in which all the serious content is in a link. Summarize.