# Read param from route into ViewBag for all views at one place

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a working MVC3 project and I need to add `string languageId` as the first param in a route, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductRoute",
    "{languageId}/products/{slug}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Product"} 
);
```

The `languageId` is only needed for rendering of views, so I'd like to avoid adding it as a named argument to all of my actions. Ideally I should be able to add it once in a viewbag use it in all dependant views (all views share the same master page).

I could override `Initialize` in the controller, read the route param and store it, but then I'll need to inject it into a view in every action, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answers. I ended up doing the following:

I created a `BaseController` that all other controllers inherit and have overridden it's `Initialize method` like so:

```
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        ViewBag.LanguageId = requestContext.RouteData.Values["languageId"] ?? NamedConsts.DefaultLangId;
    }
```

`NamedConsts` is just my class that holds application-static data, like a default language. I can now use `ViewBag.LanguageId` anywhere downstream. The only problem is that ViewBag is dynamic and therefore I have to cast `ViewBag.LanguageId` to `string` everywhere. If anyone has a better solution that fits the requirements I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is for internationalization of your project?

Here is a good blog post (a two part series) that helped me with one of the projects I'm currently working on: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

And another great post from [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) that should answer your question: [ASP.NET MVC language change link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494824/asp-net-mvc-language-change-link)

Comment: Not only for i18n, but generally how to store some information at the beginning of the request pipeline so that it's available everywhere down to a view in the same-request-context. Thank you for the links however, they are helpful on other subjects.

Answer (score 0):

When I ignore the problem of getting the language ID value from the route param and concentrate on your own comment about how to store some information at the beginning of the request pipeline, a possible solution would be the following. Note that it is 'quick and probably dirty' and may not be the best solution in terms of application design.

In global.asax:

```
public MvcApplication()  // Constructor
{
    this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
}

void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Items["LanguageId"] = 2;  // Store your language ID value here.
}
```

In a (in my case Razor) view:

```
@if ((int)HttpContext.Current.Items["LanguageId"] == 2)
{
    // Do something with the language ID.
}
```

Or access HttpContext.Items["LanguageId"] in a controller (or a ControllerBase class) and store the item in ViewBag.