# Using Global.asax file to load user preferred interface language

Tags: c#, multilingual, global-asax

I am working on a multi-lingual ASP.net web application using C# and .Net 4.0.

The web application allows the user to save his preferred language for the user interface. There is also a provision to change the user interface language using a dropdown on the website header. The web application currently uses a HttpModule to load the Culture settings each time a user changes the language in the drop down, and the selected language is persisted in a Session variable.

It is required that when a user logs in, his preferred language be used for the user interface. Is Global.asax Session_Start method a good place to get the user settings and load it in a session? What are the other options?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6494896/1373170

Answer (score 0):

We do the same and use `Application_AuthenticateRequest`